# Querying by Key in Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I need to get entity by user key that is setted as Id for User entity. Now I want to query all entities that have same key that user has. How can I do that?

Comment: Question is unclear. Key is supposed to be unique value, so you going to get just one value for given key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, now I found solution myself:

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Entity.class, "user == userParam");
            query.declareParameters("com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key userParam");
```